# Wordpress url thumbnail for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try to get the url thumbnail of my custom post type but that's don't work, can I have some help please.

My var is $image_url.

The href is empty

Here my loop :

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'partenaires', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'ASC'));
            $i = 0;

            $partners_name = get_field('partners_name');
            $col1 = $col2 = $col3 = '';

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();

            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id);
            $image_url = $image[0];

            $article = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="partnership__canva">';
            $article .= '<div class="partnership__visual" style="background-image: url("'. $image_url .'");"></div>';
            $article .= '<div class="partnership__text">';
            $article .= '<p class="partnership__name">'. get_post_meta($id, 'partners_name', true) .'</p>';
            $article .= '<h3 class="artnership__company">'. get_the_title() .'</h3>';
            $article .= '</div>';
            $article .= '</a>';

            switch($i % 3) {
                case 0:
                    $col1 .= $article;
                break;
                case 1:
                    $col2 .= $article;
                break;
                case 2:
                    $col3 .= $article;
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }

            $i++;

            endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post, $size )` instead of

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id);
$image_url = $image[0];
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/